# Grades of confirm actions

Tags: confirmation

I am currently working on a standard for confirming destructive actions, which I have to split into four levels:

1. no confirmation necessary
2. ???
3. a simple dialog that explains what the dangers are
4. a dialog that explains the dangers and requires an unusual action to confirm.

Now, level 2 should be more intrusive than level 1, but less than level 3 and it needs to work with touch as well as with mouse and keyboard.

I already implemented an undo function, that's why level 1 exists at all, but my supervisor wants something even more secure.

What are some good patterns to do this?

- Double click is annoying and will lead to spam clicking
- Long press takes too long and is unconventional on desktop
- Having a flyout is a middle ground, as it doesn't excel or suck at any specific thing

Comment: Can you explain why you need 4 levels? Following KISS, there should only be (1) and (3) (plus undo, of course, for both). I especially don't understand the (need for the) difference between (3) and (4)?

Comment: Maybe, "show a toast message at top right corner that automatically disappears after some time"?

Comment: @virtualnobi 1 & 3 are for KISS, 2 is for my supervisor, and 4 is for extremely critical stuff like deleting accounts.

Answer (score 3):

In my application, I didn't want users to be likely to accidentally delete things, but I also didn't want it to be too much effort to delete as it's easy to undelete.

I settled on a dropdown button:

[image: delete button in red, confirm delete underneath in dropdown]

- It works using any input method: mouse, fat fingered phone taps, keyboard, screen reader.
- While I can't think of any applications that specifically have a delete button like this, it's obvious what needs to be done to actually delete something. Dropdown buttons in general are common across devices and operating systems.
- While you can accidentally delete something, it's less likely to happen because you need more than a single click/tap/etc. In fact, it's even not a proper double click because you have to move your mouse to confirm the delete, even if it's a very short distance.
- It was extremely [easy to do in the library I'm using](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/).

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe programs, a window appears with information about the change that is about to be made with two buttons and a checkbox:

- `OK` to continue with the action
- `Cancel` to go back and abort the action
- `Don't show again` to avoid repetitive alerts when the user is already sure of the consequences

[image]

Comment: that would be a Level 3, i am searching for something less intrusive

Comment: Level 3 is a danger alert, this is just info and the user can decide to see it again or not.

Comment: maybe i wasn't specific enough, but what i wanted to describe as level 3 in my original question is exactly like the image you shared.
that is too disruptive to user flow, i only want to prevent slips on Level 2, not mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the user drag something to a trash on desktop, or swipe left on mobile. Both are understood deletion gestures for their devices, and are less intrusive than a dialog.

You could also put the Delete function in a dropdown menu, which will make the user have to pull down the menu and then click on the Delete action.

Comment: the first two ideas are out, since the same interaction must be used for both, but i am going to try the last one right now.